# Sampling a QPSK signal in Simulink, changing the bit rate and sample rate

Tags: sampling, qpsk, simulink

my goal is to sample a signal that I generate in Simulink and do some "real time" DSP. I want to try implement some signal classification techniques I have been learning.

I tried to make a very basic QPSK signal and send some randomly generated variables over the path, no noise added:

[image]

I am able to sample it at my designed sample frequency of 1 MHz, the problem is, my bit rate is always 1. I cant spread my bits out over multiple samples using the Random Integer generator.

How can I sample at fs= 1 MHz but have a bit rate of f_bit=100 kHz:

[image]

I feel my random integer needs to sample at 100 kHz but my actual scope sampling needs to be at 1 MHz, has anyone delt with this?